# Deconstructing object conditionally React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, create-react-app, react-hook-form

I am currently using `react-hook-forms` in a create-react-app. I have componentised the Form usage to make sure that i can re-use it in other location. I am trying to deconstruct an object and i am pretty sure its causing an issue.

**Problem:**

The code worked fine until i introduced `createLoading` check. The `oppLoading` seems to be working fine alone. They return `boolean` **true** or **false** and there is always a default state.

However, with the code below, i get the following error

**TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'ref' of '.for' as it is undefined.**

It doesn't give me much information or where to focus. The error seems to be coming from **react-hook-form**, specifically **onDomRemove.ts** on **line 15**.

```
  12 | const observer = new MutationObserver((): void => {
  13 |   for (const field of Object.values(fieldsRef.current)) {
  14 |     if (field && field.options) {
> 15 |       for (const { ref } of field.options) {
     | ^  16 |         if (isDetached(ref)) {
  17 |           removeFieldEventListenerAndRef(field);
  18 |         }
```

**Where i think the problem is:** FormContainer.tsx

```
    <form
        {...(props.onSubmit && {
            onSubmit: handleSubmit(onSubmit),
        })}
        {...(props.onBlur && {
            onBlur: handleSubmit(onSubmit),
        })}
        className="opportunity--form"
    >
```

**Question:**

Am i deconstructing this right or what would be the right way of deconstructing?

**FormContainer.tsx**:

```
const FormContainer: React.FC<FormContainerProps> = (props) => {
    const { handleSubmit } = useFormContext();
    const { loading: oppLoading } = useSelector((state: ApplicationState) => state.save_opportunity_state);
    const { loading: createLoading } = useSelector((state: ApplicationState) => state.creation_state);

    const onSubmit = async (values: any) => {
        try {
            if (props.onBlur) {
                return await props.onBlur(values);
            }
            if (props.onSubmit) {
                return await props.onSubmit(values);
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
        }
    };

    if (oppLoading || createLoading) {
        return <CircularProgress size="80px" color="primary" />;
    }

    return (
        <form
            {...(props.onSubmit && {
                onSubmit: handleSubmit(onSubmit),
            })}
            {...(props.onBlur && {
                onBlur: handleSubmit(onSubmit),
            })}
            className="opportunity--form"
        >
            {props.children}
        </form>
    );
};
```

**Form.tsx**

```
export function Form({ onSubmit, onBlur, ...props }: any) {
    return (
        <FormProvider {...props}>
            <FormContainer onSubmit={onSubmit} onBlur={onBlur}>
                {props.children}
            </FormContainer>
            <CreateResults />
        </FormProvider>
    );
}
```

**Usage:**

```
        <Form onSubmit={onSubmit} {...form}>
            ...fields here
        </Form>
```

Comment: I believe this is a bug at RHF, I am patching this.

Comment: Thanks @Bill i posted it in the RHF discussions as well.

Comment: can you share the link?

Comment: https://github.com/react-hook-form/react-hook-form/discussions/2707 is the link, and the issue is already fixed in v6.5.3 or later.